# Accidentally deleted my htaccess file on cpanel

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

I accidentally deleted htaccess file.

I downloaded it before I did so and then afterwards I re-uploaded it to my public_html folder, but I can't get to the WP login anymore. It just gives me a 404 error.

Why doesn't it start working when I just re-upload?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. It was simply because when I downloaded the file, the period in front of ".htaccess" was removed. When uploaded, it was still removed. However, I simply edited the file name in cpanel from "htaccess" to ".htaccess" and it started working again.